# Slackware and SELinux

Tags: security, kernel, selinux, slackware

I would like to learn and play with SELinux on Slackware, my distro of choice. The kernel already includes SELinux code, so that is not a problem. Slackware does not ship with PAM, and I would prefer to avoid it if possible.

Is this simply a matter of obtaining the userland tools, and compiling without PAM support, or is there more to it?

Comment: This question needs an updated answer after slackware 15.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.nsa.gov/research/selinux/list-archive/0211/thread_body5.shtml):

"SELinux isn't inherently dependent on PAM or kerberos. If your system is not using PAM, then you'll need to adjust the configure options in utils/Makefile and the flags in the newrole and run_init Makefiles. Likewise with the configure options for kerberos in utils/Makefile.

But I can't really recommend that you proceed down this path. Porting SELinux to Slackware properly requires more than just hacking up configure options and Makefiles."

Josh